# Manage data differently base on route - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and just can't figure out how mange basic scenario, here it is :

My route are defined this way :

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/list', {
        templateUrl: 'list.html',
        controller: 'studentCtrl'
      }).
      when('/detail/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'detail.html',
        controller: 'studentCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/list'
      });
  }]);
```

Im my list view, my `$scope` will have a model variable which will contain a list of students. In my detail view, my model variable will contain a single student. My question is how I can manage this at `controller` level. Right now I have the following code, which always return a list of student :

```
app.controller('studentCtrl', function($scope,) {             

   $scope.model= [
      { Name : 'Nicolas', Age: 30, Email: 'nick@gmail.com' }, 
      { Name : 'Paul', Age: 45, Email: 'paul@gmail.com' },
      { Name : 'Mary', Age: 17, Email: 'mary@gmail.com' },
   ];

});
```

I would need to be able, based on some condition, to fill model with a list OR a single student. Is the best approach to do this by injecting $routeParams to my controller function ? Am I completely off the track here ?

P.S *I'm aware managing data directly in my controller is not the best approach, using factory or service are probably best practices, I'm just not there yet since I'm still in a learning process.*

Comment: Ideally you'd have two different controllers. In your detail controller, grab the `id` of the `routeParams` and use it to get the necessary info.

Comment: @tymeJV So in an ideal world, every view should have its own controller ?

Comment: Typically yes - unless both views share an overwhelming amount of controller logic... even then, it becomes confusing having only some of the logic apply to certain views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if you use the [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) service component it can check for a present id in the url.

$routeParams lets AngularJS match url parameters set up when configuring $routeProvider. For example, the followint statement:

- when('/detail/:id', {...

Means:

- $routeParams.id in the controller will return watever value is set in the url

SO:

- http://yoursite.com/detail/10 makes $routeParams.id return an integer 10

  ```
  app.controller('studentCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {                       
     if($routeParams.id){
         'call /detail/:id url';
     } else {
         'call /list';

         $scope.model= [
             { Name : 'Nicolas', Age: 30, Email: 'nick@gmail.com' }, 
             { Name : 'Paul', Age: 45, Email: 'paul@gmail.com' },
             { Name : 'Mary', Age: 17, Email: 'mary@gmail.com' },
         ];
    }
  });
  ```

Comment: Makes senses but I think the cleanest solution will be, as @tymeJV suggest, to have two different controllers